# How do you use WatiN to click on an Ajax toolkit TabContainer header?

Tags: asp.net, testing, watin, tabcontainer

I have an ajax toolkit TabContainer control on my page with a couple tabs. In my test, I would like to switch between the tabs.

I've tried `_ie.Span("tabHeaderID").Click()`, `.MouseDown()`, `.FireEvent("onclick")`. I've tried these same methods on the parent span elements as well.

I've also tried Eval-ing some javascript to set the active index like so:

```
_ie.Eval("$get(\"ctl00_AdminContentPlaceHolder_TabContainer1\").set_activeTabIndex(1);");
```

Has anyone successfully used WatiN to switch tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not figured out how to simulate a click on the tab header. However, I do have a way to get to the second tab - just a small variation on the eval statement from my original post:

_ie.Eval("$find(\"ctl00_AdminContentPlaceHolder_TabContainer1\").set_activeTabIndex(1);");

It uses $find instead of $get to get the tab container object.